# Connecting database at the user end

Tags: vb.net, rdlc, ms-access-2013

I made a small application that getting data from a .accdb file and make some reports using .rdlc report. 
The problem is that i need to give this application to an end users woking in different workstations which means the connection string will be different than the one which i used in the application , i’ve tried to make it dynamic by letting the use select were the db file , but it will not be successful for the table adapters which been created for reporting.
Any idea how this can be solved?
Thanks all.

Comment: Can you use relative path? If the adapters have hard coded path, it will need to be changed to dynamic path. The connection string can be loaded at the beginning of the application.

Comment: How can i change the table adapters path to dynamic one? Best

Comment: Is each instance of your app using a separate database?

Comment: No it uses’s one database only

Comment: I think i need to change it in App.config file but i don’t know how ..

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using ado.net typed table adapters.

Usually, the typed table adapter uses the connection string defined in the setting file (app.config file). You can override the setting value programmatically when the application loads the setting file for the first time.

1. In the visual studio, open the project properties page (right-click the project and select Properties),
2. Select the Settings tab page.
3. On the Settings tab page, find and click '<> view code' button (it is located on the top of the tab page).

Override the files as you needed:

```
Imports System.Configuration

Namespace My

    Partial Friend NotInheritable Class MySettings
        Private Sub MySettings_SettingsLoaded(sender As Object, e As SettingsLoadedEventArgs) Handles Me.SettingsLoaded
            Item("<your connection string name here>") = "<your connection string here>"
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```